# MVC 4 View does not pass Model to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**This is the View:**

```
@model CSP1225.Models.BestOrder
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BestOfferOrder";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@{
    var payment = ViewBag.payment;
    var convert= ViewBag.Convert;
    var imgsrc = ViewBag.source;
    imgsrc = imgsrc+ Model.Best.Image;
    var priceLE = convert * Model.Best.Price;
}

@using(@Html.BeginForm("BestOfferNewOrder","Order",Model,FormMethod.Post,null))
{
    <label>Item Name:</label>
    @Html.ValueFor(r=>r.Best.Name)

    <br />
    <label>Price:</label>
    @Html.ValueFor(r=>r.Best.Price)<p>$</p>

    <br />
    <label>Price in LE:</label> 
    <p>@priceLE LE</p>  
    @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.Payment, new SelectList(payment, "PaymentMethodId", "Name"));
    <button type="submit">Save Order</button>
}
```

**This is the Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BestOfferNewOrder(BestOrder model)
{
    var order = new Order();
    order.BestOfferID = model.Best.ID;
    order.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
    order.Fees = 0;
    order.TotalPrice = model.Best.Price;
    MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
    var UserId = _db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.Email == user.Email).FirstOrDefault().ID;
    order.UserID = UserId;
    order.PaymentMethod = model.Payment;
    _db.Orders.Add(order);
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return View("ViewOrders");
}
```

**This is the Model:**

```
public class BestOrder
{
    public BestOfferModel Best { get; set; }
    public byte Payment { get; set; }
}
public class BestOfferModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal price { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

I Don't know what's wrong , the View passes only **payment** in the Model to the Controller, not the whole Model. Can some tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("BestOfferNewOrder","Order",Model,FormMethod.Post,null))
{
```

to this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("BestOfferNewOrder","Order",FormMethod.Post))
{
```

Comment: it works well but i don't understand why.. can u please explain to me ?

Comment: The @ before HTML is not necessary, but passing the `Model` in the `BeginForm` was the real problem I think. That argument is used for the RouteValues. The fields in your form are automatically converted to a model when posting to the server when using a strongly typed view.